# javafx single-row tableview: do I need to use an observable list?

Tags: javafx, tableview

I have a TableView that consists of a single row, which is implemented using an object with relevant String and Float properties. To make the object observable to the TableView, this single object is put into a list thus:

```
    private  ObservableList<MyObject> myObjectList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(); 
MyObject myObject= new MyObject ("myStringLiteral", myFloat, anotherParameter, etc);
myObjectList.add(myObject);   //a single-element list
```

I swap objects in and out of this list, but there is only ever one element in the list at any one time. The corresponding TableView only ever has one row.
This seems inefficient to implement it using an observable list. Can a tableview observe an object directly, without having to put it in a list first?

Comment: Why use a table view at all then?

Comment: I want to use the functionality of the tableview as a UI, ie render a neatly-alligned row of cells which can be edited, so data can be presented to and manipulated by the user. Also to maintain consistency between this and other tables which have more than one row. 

Are you suggesting there is another controller I can use for this application?

Comment: ListView with horizontal orientation will work. but you will have to style it with css to fit your needs :)